# What is the category of models?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I'm taking a look at *Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups* by Michael Demazure and Peter Gabriel, and I'm confused about some terminology.  Early in the book it says "A $\mathbb{Z}$-functor is a functor from the category of models $M$ into the category of sets $E$.  The category of $\mathbb{Z}$-functors is denoted $ME$."

What is the category of models?  This book uses some rather nonstandard terminology, for example when they say *geometric space*, they mean a locally ringed space, and *spectral space* seems to refer to what everyone else calls a scheme.

Comment: I would assume (but this is a complete guess) that a model is a local model i.e an affine scheme.

Answer (score 1):

See "General Conventions" on page xiii.  They have a set $U$ of "small" sets and a model is a ring whose underlying set is in $U$.